# PHP 7 Script not display errors, or writing them to the log

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-reporting

I've been bashing my head trying to port some super old PHP script to PHP 7.0, which is proving impossible because I can't figure out what the errors are! If I implement some sort of syntax or parse error, the script happily shows those to me, but I cant get any errors that tell me my function is undefined when I try to call `lkasjdfalkjshdfasdF();` (which obviously isn't set).

Things I've tried:

This is my `.htaccess` file in the same directory as my script

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors         on
php_flag html_errors            on
php_flag log_errors             on
php_value error_log             "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
```

I also have this at the top of my script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If I add `echho 'test';` on one of my lines, it shows the following on the page, and in the error log

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''test'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /domains/stupidphpscripts.com/public_html/lib/dumbfile.php on line 200
```

If I add `echo asdfasdf();` on one of my lines, I get no output, and there's nothing in the error log.

I even wrote this silly function

```
$DebugPointCointer = 0;

function DebugPoint() {
    global $DebugPointCointer;

    echo "Debug point $DebugPointCointer on line " . debug_backtrace(1)[0]['line'] . "\n";

    $DebugPointCointer++;
}
```

So I could make sure that the script was failing where I suspected, but in all honesty, that information didn't really help me.

What's left to try?

Comment: Is the /var/log/apache2/error.log empty, and what are the permissions?

Comment: If that log file is really empty, then that is the wrong file.

Comment: @DarrellUlm It's not empty, the error that I noted was working successfully goes into the log file, but the error that isn't displaying anywhere also isn't displaying in that log file, but the log file is clearly working with the working errors in the same script

Answer (score -1):

E_ALL is not enough.

use:

`error_reporting(-1);` // for all and the future (still un inplemented features) in develop enviroment!

Do you really run on the correct host?

- May be a vhost that stores to a different error log?

Does the main scripts have any ats "@" -> @functionToCall() included which suspress anything ?